Bevel incomplete
My bevel doesn't apply on all the angles of my object. I feel like the solution is under my nose but I can't figure it out, I tried changing the angle but nothing.
Should I mention that I applied the bevel through the material and not by Ctrl + B


In the Bevel modifier, under Geometry, disable the Clamp Overlap option and you'll see that the bevel will be larger, but of course disabling this option will make some faces overlap, which you probably don't want.
What you could do is using the Limit Method > Weight instead of Angle, then assign a different Bevel Weight value to your edges, depending on the width you want for each of them, in order to avoid overlapping (select an edge, open the N panel > Item > Edges Data > Bevel Weight):


it worked! with the weight in limit method, thank you so much mooboots you're very helpful :)
